# MS Access Error 3464 - using variable for field in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to run a query using vba with a variable in my INSERT INTO statement to select the field to use.  I've done some research and found some similar problems where the solution was to create a function with a variable and to call the function in my sql statement, but I am still running into issues.  If I hard-code the field, it works.  Thanks in advance.  Here is my code so far:

```
Option Compare Database
Public var As Variant

Public Function GetVar() As String
    GetVar = var
End Function

Sub Build()

Dim varX As String
Dim count As Integer
Dim AccountName As String

For count = 1 To 50

    varX = DLookup("[AcctName]", "AcctTable", "[AcctNum] =" & count)
    AccountName = varX
    var = varX


    StrSql = "INSERT INTO [Testresult] (Year, Period, Entity, Region, [Product Recall], Account, AcctVal)" & _
    " SELECT Year, Period, Entity, Region, [Product Recall], """ & AccountName & """, getvar() FROM [MFTest] "

    CurrentDb().Execute StrSql, dbFailOnError

    Next count

End Sub
```

Comment: Add `Debug.Print StrSql` to the line before `CurrentDb.Execute`, then run the code.  When you get error 3464 again, copy the `StrSql` text from the Immediate window and show it to us.  You can use Ctrl+g to go to the Immediate window.  Also what is the value of `var` when you get the error?

Comment: Here is the printout: INSERT INTO [Testresult] (Year, Period, Entity, Region, [Product Recall], Account, AcctVal) SELECT Year, Period, Entity, Region, [Product Recall], "Other_Gross_Premium_Written", getvar() FROM [MFTest] .  Var = "Other_Gross_Premium_Written".  I'm trying to pull the field Other_Gross_Premium_Written from the table and I think its the quotes that are the issue?

Comment: Then do you get what you want if you change `""" & AccountName & """` to `" & AccountName & "`?

Comment: try .....,[" & accountname & "],...

Comment: Also change `Year` to `[Year]` both places in the statement to distinguish the field from the `Year()` function.

Comment: Yes!  Thankyou!  Just to clarify, I replaced the getvar() with [" & accountname & "].  What I am trying to do is to show the Accountname first and then the Account value in the next column.  It was the syntax to bring in the field that I could get.

Comment: Hmm, been awhile.  How do I mark this as solved?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are taking every record from `MfTest` and adding each of these for account numbers 1-50 into your new table.  If that's the case, would something like this work:

```
INSERT INTO [Testresult]
([Year], [Period], [Entity], [Region], [Product Recall], [Account], [AcctVal])
SELECT
  [MFTest].[Year], [MFTest].[Period], [MFTest].[Entity], [MFTest].[Region],
  [MFTest].[Product Recall], [AcctTable].[AccountName], [AcctTable].[AccountName]
FROM
  [MFTest],
  [AcctTable]
WHERE
  [AcctTable].[AcctNum] between 1 and 50
```

As a single statement rather than within a loop?

The only caveat is that your code above should also include blanks where there is no such account number -- which perhaps you wanted but I would intuitively suspect not, as you would have repeat blanks for every non-account number.

By the way, this is a cartesian join, which is usually done by accident, but in this case it seems to be what you wanted.

If this doesn't work, I'd recommend adding parameters to your insert query.  Even if you can get it working, Parameters (bind variables) are a better practice and will save you headaches in the long run.

Comment: Hambone, actually what I was trying to do was to reformat a multi-column data table to a single column table.  I was trying to use a variable to select the data column, but couldn't get the syntax right.  Nathan_Sav and HansUp answered my problem.  Thanks.